# Why doesn’t my controller conform to NSObjectProtocol?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols

i am using Xcode and swift 3 to develop a project for me. What i am trying to do is like below.

```
class SCViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate{
    //code here
}
```

But this gives me an error that **SCViewController** does not conform to protocol **NSObjectProtocol**.

I want to conform to both UIViewController and AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate. Please help me through this.

Comment: Are you sure about the error? `UIViewController` inherits from `UIResponder`, which in turn inherits from `NSObject`. And `NSObject` implements `NSObjectProtocol`. In other words, this should work.

Comment: We need to see more code, I can't recreate this as you have it. Have you tried cleaning your build folder and deleting your derived data? (If I delete the inheritance from UIViewController, I get that error.)

Comment: Yes i did. And i am sure about the error.

Comment: I'm able to run your code without any error. Have you cleaned your project? Try to put this code in another project, and you'll not get any error as I hope

Comment: Do you maybe have a typo in the actual code? If you misspell `UIViewController` you will get two errors, but the shown error will be that you don't conform to `NSObjectProtocol`

Comment: I tried putting into another project too and also cleaned more than once but still the same.

Comment: Go to your issue navigator (command-4), is the only error `Type 'SCViewController' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'` ?

Comment: I don't know what's happening. Sometimes i see this error in every class in my project and sometimes the error is gone with some new errors like 'UIViewController' does not have member 'viewDidLoad'. I tried clearing the derived data, cleaning and finally making new project and copy the code to that project. But all fails with same issues.

Comment: actually have you got bridgning header and objective c code in your project? That would explain thia behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

You need to implement the protocol functions in order to conform to that protocol. Without that the protocol conformance is there useless, don't ya think? :) Anyway it's always better to extend the class via protocol in extension, like this:

```
extension SCViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate{
    //code here
}
```

Anyway more extensive description: As you can see, the delegates implements as "superProtocol" NSObjectProtocol,

see this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutputobjectsdelegate

So just implement the NSObjectProtocol functions and you will be fine... Happy coding :)

Edit: After realising I am a complete idiot and forgetting the essential things -> this should work, because the UIViewController class is subclass to UIResponder which is subclass to NSObject, therefore there might be problem with the class name or something like that... Would try to force the compiler to do strange things what it would do... like this:

```
extension SCViewController: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate{
    //code here
}
```

btw this above should definitely work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not helping. I know i have to implement the methods if i conform to a protocol but NSObjectDelegate is not inherited in my project.

Comment: Ahhh I seee your point Here, I am sorry... You have to Subclass NSObject, which is really strange, because UIViewController should be the NSObjectProtocol indirect subclass by UIResponder standing in the middle of these too.. try to delete derived data, clean the project and run it again.. if it won't work - I suppose you implemented the AVFoundation framework into file?

Comment: and have you checked you are not declaring the viewCOntroller somewhere else?

Comment: edited the answer, please tell me if the last piece of code works or not...

Comment: Yes i did implement AVFoundation Framework. Whys is that a problem